# JFileChooser is very slow when using windows look and feel

Tags: java, swing

I am getting a load time of approximately 21-40 secs when using JFileChooser along with windows look and feel.If i remove look and feel the code runs very fast.I guess the problem is while initializing `new JFileChooser("path");`. Can someone help me ? here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() throws HeadlessException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Demo");

        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("./feedback"));
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fc.showDialog(frame, "Choose");
            }
        });

        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
        pane.add(btn1);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: On what version of Java and Windows ? I have tried this on a **Windows 7 with java 1.8.0_66** without a problem. (not really up to date on this workstation....). Also on a VM with **XP and Java 1.6.0_23** (not at all up to date on this one !!!)

Comment: m using windows 10 along with java 1.7.0_17. can an upgrade fix it ?

Comment: Just updated my comment, it is probably not java, it works fine with java 6 and 8. But could be windows 10 look and fell. Don't have it at the office...

Comment: I have quickly downloaded java 1.8.0_161,i can still see the problem.thanks for the quick reply AxelH.

Comment: @AxelH Try to navigate to `C:\Windows\System32`. Icon loading is slow.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I would not say slow, it took ~1s. far from those 40s as mentioned. Again, not using a Win10... only have 7 and XP.

Comment: Then try to navigate to my downloads folder. Even a native windows file selection form is slow.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Mine is empty but as you said, this has nothing to do with swing, but the rendering of the dialog. I have open a network folder with 18k file, it was renderer in 2sec ... I will confirm the result with Windows 10 this evening when I get access to one. Might be the rendering with the new look and fell that is incorrect.

Comment: What kind of file? If it's only some *.doc or *.pdf, then its reasonably fast. If it's all kind of *.exe, *.ico or similar, it will take a while.

Comment: I did notice a noticeable difference loading a folder like System32 (a few seconds, 5sec max) on Windows 10 still with java 1.8.0_151 . This is a different system but again, far from the result of OP. Please try to describe the content of the folder taking so much time to be rendered. I would guess those icons are a bit heavier to load on Windows 10 due to the HIDPI screen these days?

Comment: I am talking about the initial load time by that i mean the actual jfilechooser to pop up, not the load time of any file.am running a harddisk clocked at 5400 rpm.i believe the run time varies with an ssd,if your using one.try loading the actual gui for more number of times you will see a lag.sorry i didn't noticed your comments last day.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and at least in my case it had nothing to do with the version of Windows or Java.

During creation of the JFileChooser the *Windows look and feel* already tries to calculate the size of the combobox of the current directory by asking for the icons of all visible items - including the icons of network shares. And in my case some of my network shares were not available.

That was my stacktrace on Java 8 and Windows 10:

```
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0]
    Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
    LockSupport.park(Object) line: 175  
    FutureTask<V>.awaitDone(boolean, long) line: 429    
    FutureTask<V>.get() line: 191
    Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker.invoke(Callable<T>) line: 582   
    ShellFolder.invoke(Callable<T>, Class<E>) line: 518 
    ShellFolder.invoke(Callable<T>) line: 504   
    Win32ShellFolder2.getIcon(boolean) line: 968    
    WindowsFileSystemView(FileSystemView).getSystemIcon(File) line: 243 
    WindowsFileChooserUI$WindowsFileView.getIcon(File) line: 1300   
    JFileChooser.getIcon(File) line: 1609   
    WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(JList, Object, int, boolean, boolean) line: 998 
    BasicListUI.updateLayoutState() line: 1361
    BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState() line: 1311
    BasicListUI$Handler.valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent) line: 2623 
    DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(int, int, boolean) line: 184 
    DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(int, int) line: 164  
    DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged() line: 211  
    DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(int, int, int, int, boolean) line: 405    
    DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(int, int, int, int) line: 415 
    DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(int, int) line: 459  
    BasicComboPopup$1(JList<E>).setSelectedIndex(int) line: 2216    
    BasicComboPopup.setListSelection(int) line: 1186    
    BasicComboPopup.access$300(BasicComboPopup, int) line: 65   
    BasicComboPopup$Handler.itemStateChanged(ItemEvent) line: 1015  
    WindowsFileChooserUI$2(JComboBox<E>).fireItemStateChanged(ItemEvent) line: 1223 
    WindowsFileChooserUI$2(JComboBox<E>).selectedItemChanged() line: 1280   
    WindowsFileChooserUI$2(JComboBox<E>).contentsChanged(ListDataEvent) line: 1330  
    WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel(AbstractListModel<E>).fireContentsChanged(Object, int, int) line: 118   
    WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Object) line: 1140  
    WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(File) line: 1111    
    WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.access$800(WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel, File) line: 1041    
    WindowsFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(PropertyChangeEvent) line: 730  
    WindowsFileChooserUI.access$1100(WindowsFileChooserUI, PropertyChangeEvent) line: 55    
    WindowsFileChooserUI$11.propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent) line: 821   
    PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeListener[], PropertyChangeEvent) line: 335 
    PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent) line: 327 
    PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(String, Object, Object) line: 263  
    JFileChooser(Component).firePropertyChange(String, Object, Object) line: 8434   
    JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(File) line: 598    
    JFileChooser.<init>(File, FileSystemView) line: 344 
    JFileChooser.<init>(File) line: 326 
    FileChooser.<clinit>() line: 15 
    ...
```

So I see two solutions:

Initialize your file chooser long before you need it, as mentioned by Joop Eggen, or install your own UI, which tries to retrieve the icon in extra threads and only returns those icons which are available immediately.

Comment: Holy sh.., thanks a lot. Although I also narrowed the problem down to the point where the JFileChooser starts to traverse the directory structure I never would have thought about an inaccessible network share causing that inconvenience.

Comment: Echoing that I had the same issue - Unbeknownst to me I had a network drive drop and suddenly my JFileChooser was taking forever. I thought it was a JDK 17 thing as I had recently updated, but clearing the bad drive was enough to get it back to normal

Answer (score 2):

One solution (of many years ago) would be to use the java.awt FileChooser.
Better seems to preload a shared JFileChooser in the background:

A field with a Future:

```
FutureTask<JFileChooser> futureFileChooser = new FutureTask<>(JFileChooser::new);
```

Then on initialisation do:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(futureFileChooser);
```

So when finally a JFileChooser is desired, get it from the Future.

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = futureFileChooser.get();
```

If this is done within the loading time it still blocks, but already for less time. This solution will not work when the first thing done is opening a JFileChooser.

I probably cannot convince you to switch to JavaFX if the native look and feel is wanted that much.

Comment: if i could give up on look, the running time is very less. @Joop Eggen.

Comment: Some look&feels are nice. Nimbus is a bit Macintoshish, but I believe Plastic and some other third party themes might fit in in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code helped me and i haven't found any issue since then.

```
WindowsFileChooserUI wui = new WindowsFileChooserUI(filechosser);
wui.installUI(filechosser);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to remove from the desktop the shortcuts to LibreOffice Writer and Calc, the ones that were made automatically during the installation. Made another shortcuts manually (with right click drag and drop) and those didn't slow the opening of FileChooser.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the knowledge base. On win 10 java 18

javax.swing.UIManager$LookAndFeelInfo[CDE/Motif com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel]

works *really* fast. Note: there is a space between the Motif and the com. in the above.

Comment: MotifLookAndFeel is deprecated.

```@Deprecated(since="13", forRemoval=true)
```